# How to deploy Swing application with JWS in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, deployment, java-web-start

**Is there proper guideline on how to deploy Swing application with JWS?**

Here is what I have been trying

Created Swing application with Netbeans. And trying to deploy ready application with Java web start.

Project Property -> Application -> Web start, Enabled Web start, fixed all necessary fields. 
By using Tomcat or WAMP server, I was able to run jnlp file, it downloads necessary libraries and right after launch I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

But json.simple jar file is in classpath and application is running normal locally (without JWS).

**Why despite having library in classpath, I get NoClassDefFoundError error?**

jnlp file seem to have it listed `<jar href="lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>`.
Surfed around net but couldn't find a fix for the issue. Anyone had similar issues, please help! And Please ask for clarification before marking this question as duplicate, thanks!

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: thanks, did try, but could not detect any serious issues though!

Comment: Found solution to my 2nd Question. replacing library with [_other json-simple_](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1) fixed the issue.